# Command yarn build throw Error: listen EPERM: operation not permitted 0.0.0.0

Tags: node.js, webpack, sylius, webpack-encore

I installed sylius 1.12 on hosting and everything went fine except `yarn build` command:

```
Running webpack ...

node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EPERM: operation not permitted 0.0.0.0:14162
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/public_html/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/worker.js:68:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EPERM',
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 14162
}

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/public_html/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Timed out waiting for sync-rpc server to start (it should respond with "pong" when sent "ping"):

node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:14162
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 14162
}


    at waitForAlive (/public_html/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:85:11)
    at start (/public_html/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:41:3)
    at sendMessage (/public_html/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:133:17)
    at createClient (/public_html/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:173:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/public_html/node_modules/@symfony/webpack-encore/lib/plugins/eslint.js:13:32)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

Each execution of command trying to connect to different port. I would appreciate if somebody could help it's very frustrating. I'm not frontend developer so I don't even know what this command should do.